# get request object array in node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

i'm using AngularJs for client app and backend running using Node.js.
i have to send some data from client side to backend both header and body.

**AngularJs code**

```
$scope.checked_pages=
[
  {
   page_name : BMW,
   pg_id : 123
  },
   {
   page_name : Audi,
   pg_id : 12334
   },
   {.....},
   {......}
];

  $http.post(
      'www.abc.com/../.../index?name=ab',{data: $scope.checked_pages})
    .then(function mySuccess(response) {
       console.log("success ", response);
     }, function myError(response) {
      console.log("Error ", response);

    });
```

**Node.js**

```
        exports.index = (req, res) => {
        var client_name = req.query.name;
        var pgid=req.body.pg_id;
        var pgname=req.body.page_name;

        req.checkBody('name', 'Client name cannot be empty').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('page_name', 'FB page name cannot be empty').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('pg_id', 'FB page id cannot be empty').notEmpty();

    const errors = req.validationErrors();

      if (errors) {
        response.fail(res, response.message.parameter_missing, errors);
        return;
      }else{
        var msg = {
                msg: 'data received !'
              };
       response.success(res, msg);
      }
};
```

**Problem**

when i send body data like below (single object),i can get body data in node side.but when i send `array object` like above, node side display error.

```
$scope.checked_pages=
  {
   page_name : BMW,
   pg_id : 123
  };
```

error messages 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause of Error:**

```
responseObject: {page_name: "this is a field inside the response"}
responseArray: [{page_name: "this is a field inside the object inside the response"}]
```

The Array does not have any fields.
  The Array has only objects in it and no fields, therefor the test who is looking for fields in the response will execute error.

**Possible solution:** does not rely on 'req.checkBody'

```
exports.index = (req, res) => {
    var client_name = req.query.name;
    var pgid=req.body.pg_id;
    var pgname=req.body.page_name;

    req.body.forEach((dataItem) => {
        /* WRITE YOUR OWN CODE BELOW */
        // is 'name' field empty?
        // is 'page_name' field empty?
        // is 'pg_id' field empty?
    })

  // Do something with the new knowledge and create 'errors' variable

  if (errors) {
    response.fail(res, response.message.parameter_missing, errors);
    return;
  }else{
    var msg = {
            msg: 'data received !'
          };
   response.success(res, msg);
  }
};
```